# msxml6.dll HTTP GET works but HTTP POST does not

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` to connect to a simple test web service like so:

```
oRequest.open "POST", "http://www.foobar.com:84/Service1.asmx/GetServerTime", False
```

The request envelope is empty. The test web service is a very simple one that returns the time and does not require any inputs.

The web service is running fine, I can successfully use HTTP GET to connect to it, but when I try to use HTTP POST the ASP throws up a "The parameter is incorrect" error when I send the request.

Comment: If the parameter is incorrect, maby you should show us what it looks like.

Comment: For future reference, you'll get better results editing the question to include missing information than you will by posting it in the comments as the comments tend to get missed by future readers.